# Running asp.net through fast-mono-cgi, random crashes System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, mono

Running an ASP.net 4 site through fastcgi-mono (v5.12) with a nginx front end. Occasionally  get a problem where nginx and fastcgi-mono stays up, but the site is down with an error. It crashes on every connect once this has happened

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Could not find a part of the path
>   "/tmp/nginx-temp-aspnet-0/dbba5170/ngulyqg7.tmp"

I've checked and the path is not there after nginx-temp-aspnet-0. The nginx logs show

> *219809 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request
>   to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: anonymisedimagetransfer,
>   request: "GET
>   /xnat-ctc/bundles/jquery?v=v76fAns59-4kGkYyDyEXyw9RgnmvJyXSd0eFBt05RzE1
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8999", host: "127.0.0.1",
>   referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/" 2019/06/27 09:00:25 [error] 9479#9479:
>   *219803 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: anonymisedimagetransfer,
>   request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"

The application log reports

> [Thread Pool Worker] ERROR - Could not find a part of the path
>   "/tmp/nginx-temp-aspnet-0/dbba5170/xhr74ixf.tmp".

for each connection made.

A restart of the fastcgimono server fixes the problem without a restart of nginx. the fastcgimono server had been running for 16 days.

I've three sites running the same code behind the same nginx server. Two went down, the third is still up, but doesn't seem to have been running quite as long 2 weeks 1 day.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues You might report the developers, but things like ASP.NET 4.x and WinForms on Mono are not quite actively maintained. You really should migrate to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Granted, it's on the list of things to do,